# in AngleSharp, how can I loop through all list items (included the nested ones) and turn each one into a single list with the parent attributes

Tags: anglesharp

in AngleSharp, how can I loop through all list items (included the nested ones) and turn each one into a single list with the parent attributes. I tried code below

```
  var parser = new AngleSharp.Parser.Html.HtmlParser();
            var document = parser.Parse(theString);
            var listItemsLinq = document.QuerySelectorAll("li");
            foreach (var item in listItemsLinq)
            {
                var p = item.ParentElement.Clone(false);

                var newiTem = item.Clone(false);
                p.AppendChild(newiTem);
                item.ParentElement.ParentElement.AppendChild(p);
                item.ParentElement.RemoveChild(item);
                Response.Write(document.DocumentElement.OuterHtml);
            }
```

This gives me empty list, the list is created but the item context has not been copied over.
Example list

```
<ul>
    <li>one.</li>
    <li>two.</li>
    <li>three.</li>
    <li>Four:
    <ul>
        <li>Four-One</li>
        <li>Four-Two</li>
        <li>Four-Three</li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Five</li>
    <li>Six</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by "the item context has not been copied over". Why all that cloning if you could simply re-append?

Since you use `.Clone(false)` the children won't be copied. As such the text children also won't be copied.

Hence starting with your example

```
<ul>
    <li>one.</li>
    <li>two.</li>
    <li>three.</li>
    <li>Four:
    <ul>
        <li>Four-One</li>
        <li>Four-Two</li>
        <li>Four-Three</li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Five</li>
    <li>Six</li>
</ul>
```

We would end up with the following

```
<ul>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li></li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li></li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li></li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li></li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li></li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

The first list is empty, because it is the original list, where we have removed all items.

#### Solution 1

If you want to consider nested lists, but want them grouped, then our solution may look like (only inner part of the loop):

```
var parent = item.ParentElement;
var p = parent.Clone(false);
p.AppendChild(item);
parent.ParentElement.AppendChild(p);
```

The result is

```
<ul>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>one.</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>two.</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>three.</li>
</ul>
<ul>        
  <li>
    Four:
    <ul>        
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>Four-One</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>Four-Two</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>Four-Three</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>Five</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>Six</li>
</ul>
```

#### Solution 2

If you also want to apply this to nested lists then you only need to also loop inside the loop:

```
var parent = item.ParentElement;

while (parent.ParentElement.LocalName === 'li') {
    parent = parent.ParentElement.ParentElement;
}

var p = parent.Clone(false);
p.AppendChild(item);
parent.ParentElement.AppendChild(p);
```

This results in the flattened tree of lists consisting of a single item.

Hope this helps!